# ngrok tunnel not getting backend on mean stack app

Tags: angular, express, ngrok

App is angular 2 with express backend. To test on mobile I got an ngrok tunnel address. Ngrok console is not actually requesting the backend, so I have no errors. Everything else looks fine, just no data! 
All works fine on localhost.